# How can I get whole page with login authentication

Tags: bash, parsing, curl

site I want to:https://www.codecademy.com
I was trying to got whole HTML File and CSS File. 
then, I found HTTrack , and I used it. 
but I couldn't get web page that requires Login.
How can I got page that requires Login?
(sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

This is *that* simple as : open url in your browser, then

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> on a Mac)